# Would a 5-minute grace period for moderator messages (both directions) be useful?

Tags: feature-request, edits, grace-period, moderator-messages

I wrote a long reply (1.2k+ words) to a moderator message, and after clicking "Reply", I spotted a typo, just one typo.

Given that moderator messages are private and cannot be edited (by others), it would be useful to give users a grace period of 5 minutes, just as it is everywhere else, for users to edit the reply after sending it. It's not like spam or other inappropriate content where a grace-period edit would be harmful (e.g. make existing flags confusing) so I think it's worth it.

Can we have a grace period to edit moderator messages, both from mod to user and from user to mod?

Answer (score 6):

As a mod ... Probably not that useful as far as typos go. On the mod end a significant number of moderator messages we send are 'default' and unless we forget to suspend someone, we rarely need to resend.

Likewise most mod replies are short and we will not be grading you. Now if you blow your top and the 5 minutes will stop you from doing anything ill considered it can be useful. Then again, it would also be a culmination of a series of bad decisions

Considering mod messages are a bit of a unique case I'm not really sure it is really going to be that useful